# How to keep Organize Imports sorting order in sync between Eclipse and IntelliJ, or any IDE?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, ide

How to keep **Organize Imports sorting order** in sync between Eclipse and IntelliJ, or any IDE?

Comment: In Xcode you can keep list view items arranged in a particular order by ordering them in the underlying project's XML file. If dragging items does not work I often edit the XML file directly. Other editors don't honor the XML item order, like the Visual Studio editor. VS always displays them in alphabetical order.

Comment: @TechPassionate You mean in Java? Then use https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6546-eclipse-code-formatter

Comment: You can define the order in Eclipse in the Preferences in 'Java > Code Style > Organize Imports'

Comment: I have done the same, but when we import the same project in IntelliJ, the imports are messed up again. I'm using google style formatter in eclipse and IntelliJ. I wanted to see, if there is anything that could be configured in Google Style formatter to keep it in sync. in both the editors.